# How can I enable something like Windows-style command history traversal in bash?

Tags: bash, command-history

Personally I prefer the Windows way of command history traversal (sorry!) where each command retains its place in the history and when you return to the last-executed command it's not necessarily last in the history.

Not sure if that makes sense so I will try to explain with examples.

### Bash

Suppose I executed four commands (`one`, `two`, `three`, `four`). After this, the command history (from earliest to most recent) looks like:

- `one`
- `two`
- `three`
- `four`

Now if I press up three times, I will go back to `four`, then `three`, then `two` as expected. If I press enter, I will execute command `two`. Now the history looks like:

- `one`
- `two`
- `three`
- `four`
- `two`

If I press <kbd>↑</kbd> I will see `two`. If I press it again, I will see `four` and so on.

### Windows

Suppose I executed the same four commands (`one`, `two`, `three`, `four`). After this, the command history (from earliest to most recent) looks like:

- `one`
- `two`
- `three`
- `four`

Now if I press up three times, I will go back to `four`, then `three`, then `two` as before. If I press enter, I will execute command `two`. Now pressing <kbd>↑</kbd> again, it will still show `two`. But the history still looks like:

- `one`
- `two`
- `three`
- `four`

What this means is that I have "jumped" back to an earlier point in the history. I can now press <kbd>↑</kbd> to see `one`, or <kbd>↓</kbd> to see `three`, etc.

### Why this is useful

This is particularly useful when you have just run a series of commands and you want to run them again. It involves **significantly** less keystrokes to run the whole series again.

Is there a way to cause bash to behave the same way?

Comment: Seems a lot like [With BASH after “scrolling” up to a previous command… how to then move on to the next in this history?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/417052/with-bash-after-scrolling-up-to-a-previous-command-how-to-then-move-on-to-t)

Comment: It's not, though.  There's more to the Microsoft command history paradigm than that.  Notice what this question says about what state the history is in after the repeated command is executed.  See also [how this works with JP Software command interpreters](https://jpsoft.com/help/cmdhist.htm).

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but it may be helpful if there ends up being no true answer.

If you've executed some sequence of commands:

```
$ one
$ two
$ three
$ four

$ history
1  one
2  two
3  thee
4  four
```

and you want to execute the sequence again, you could do the following:

```
!1; !2; !3; !4
```

Or, if you want to execute subsequent commands only if the earlier ones succeeded:

```
!1 && !2 && !3 && !4
```

Then, you'll get an entry like that in your history:

```
$ history
1  one
2  two
3  three
4  four
5  one; two; three; four
6  one && two && three && four
```

Then, if you want to re-execute that sequence again, you can use the arrows or just use, for instance, `!5`

Comment: The bash  history expansion is awesome, here's a great link on many more things it can do -https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-bash-history-commands-and-expansions-on-a-linux-vps